# How can I fix this cPanel Issue?

Tags: linux, cpanel, linux-server, dedicated-server

Anytime I visit my website, I see: "Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/lib/sec/prepend.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php73/pear') in Unknown on line 0"

I use a dedicated server. How can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

I think this has to do with the php version you are currently running on your site. Simply confirm the version of the php runing

Comment: Could you offer some more details? What would change depending on the PHP version? Which version would cause the issue, and why? Which version should OP get and why?